Django cannot be recognized
        pip list

        absl-py                      2.1.0
        anaconda                     0.0.1.1
        asgiref                      3.8.1
        astunparse                   1.6.3
        beautifulsoup4               4.12.3
        bs4                          0.0.2
        certifi                      2024.2.2
        charset-normalizer           3.3.2
        click                        8.1.7
        colorama                     0.4.6
        contourpy                    1.2.1
        cycler                       0.12.1
        Django                       5.0.6
        flatbuffers                  24.3.25
        fonttools                    4.51.0
        gast                         0.5.4
        google-pasta                 0.2.0
        grpcio                       1.62.2
        h5py                         3.11.0
        idna                         3.7
        joblib                       1.4.0
        keras                        3.3.2
        kiwisolver                   1.4.5
        libclang                     18.1.1
        lxml                         5.2.2
        Markdown                     3.6
        markdown-it-py               3.0.0
        MarkupSafe                   2.1.5
        matplotlib                   3.8.4
        mdurl                        0.1.2
        ml-dtypes                    0.3.2
        mpmath                       1.3.0
        namex                        0.0.8
        nltk                         3.8.1
        numpy                        1.26.4
        opt-einsum                   3.3.0
        optree                       0.11.0
        packaging                    24.0
        pandas                       2.2.2
        pillow                       10.3.0
        pip                          24.0
        protobuf                     4.25.3
        pyfiglet                     1.0.2
        Pygments                     2.17.2
        pyparsing                    3.1.2
        Python                       3.11.4
        python-dateutil              2.9.0.post0
        pytz                         2024.1
        regex                        2024.5.10
        requests                     2.31.0
        rich                         13.7.1
        scikit-learn                 1.4.2
        scipy                        1.13.0
        six                          1.16.0
        soupsieve                    2.5
        sqlparse                     0.5.0
        style                        1.1.0
        tensorboard                  2.16.2
        tensorboard-data-server      0.7.2
        tensorflow                   2.16.1
        tensorflow-intel             2.16.1
        tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.31.0
        termcolor                    2.4.0
        Theano                       1.0.5
        threadpoolctl                3.4.0
        tqdm                         4.66.4
        typing_extensions            4.11.0
        tzdata                       2024.1
        update                       0.0.1
        urllib3                      2.2.1
        Werkzeug                     3.0.2
        wheel                        0.43.0
        wrapt                        1.16.0

I am doing a coding course where I'll be learning all about Django. From this, it is correct to assume that I am new to everything Django. In the course, I am at the point where I must install Django. The instructor said to use my computer's terminal to install Django. He also said to install Django 2.0.2, as that is the version he would be using. The command he had me use was pip3 install django==2.0.2. Everything installed normally, but when I tried to open Django with Django-admin, I was met with this error: django: The term 'django' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
I tried uninstalling Django, then installing the latest version using: pip install Django, letting my device install whatever the latest version is, but even though everything installed perfectly, I am still met with the same error when I try to start a new project with Django. I was also given alternate commands that the Bing AI Copilot gave me, such as: python -m Django startproject first_project, but that produced the same type of error, telling me that the Django commands I am trying to use cannot be recognized "as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.". I am wondering why Django isn’t working. I am using Windows 11, Dell Inspiron 16 Plus, and am wondering if maybe my device or OS is to blame for these errors. I emailed the course instructor, but have not gotten a response back. The course instructor uses MacOS, and he didn’t give any special commands for Windows devices. Asking the Bing AI Copilot, it keeps telling me to try python -m django startproject first_project, django-admin.py, or django-admin, and I keep getting the same type of error, telling me that my commands are not recognizable. Th course I am using is Django 2 & Python | The Ultimate Web Development Bootcamp, which is a course on StackSkills.com.
Below are the different commands I tried, and the errors they produced (Both in the Windows Command Prompt Terminal and the Windows Administrator: PowerShell:

Terminal: C:\Users\ngjph>pip install django Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\users\ngjph\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (5.0.6) Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.7.0 in c:\users\ngjph\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from django) (3.8.1) Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.3.1 in c:\users\ngjph\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from django) (0.5.0) Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\users\ngjph\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from django) (2024.1)

C:\Users\ngjph>python -m django --version C:\Users\ngjph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: No module named django
C:\Users\ngjph>python -m django C:\Users\ngjph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: No module named django
C:\Users\ngjph>django-admin 'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

PowerShell PS C:\Users\ngjph> pip install django Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\users\ngjph\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (5.0.6) Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.7.0 in c:\users\ngjph\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from django) (3.8.1) Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.3.1 in c:\users\ngjph\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from django) (0.5.0) Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\users\ngjph\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from django) (2024.1)

PS C:\Users\ngjph> django-admin django-admin: The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
PS C:\Users\ngjph> python Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. >>> import django Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
PS C:\Users\ngjph> django --version django: The term 'django' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
PS C:\Users\ngjph> python -m django --version C:\Users\ngjph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: No module named django

"He also said to install Django 2.0.2, as that is the version he would be using." - Just as an aside, your instructor is doing y'all a big disfavor.  Django 2.0.x was end of life in April 2019.  4.2 LTS is the earliest version that is not EOL.   And ... yes ... installing old Django on platforms with a python platform that is too new can lead to problems.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

what " coding course" do you use? You could add link in question (not in comment). And you should check how old is this course. Maybe it shows outdated information and you have to find newer course.

on my Linux I don't have command django but django-admin and command django-admin --version shows me 5.0.6 - so you try to use very old version.

instead saying "the same type of error"  better show FULL error message - and check if it EXACTLY the same. Small differences in error message may need different solutinos

@furas I edited my question, adding the coding course I am doing. You can also see the in my pip list above, I have Django 5.0.6. When I try using the command django --version or any command that has "django " in it, my computer tells me that "django : The term 'django' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

@StephenC If you look at my question and pip list above, you'll see that I have Django 5.0.6 and not the Django 2.0.2 the instructor wanted me to download, yet I am getting errors that tell me that with any command that has "django " in it, the command cannot be recognized, because "django : The term 'django' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.", regardless of what is after "django".

maybe read tutorial in official documentation: Writing your first Django app, part 1. There is no script/program django. You may only use python -m django but there should be script/program django-admin. But if you use Windows then problem can be to find /full/path/to/django-admin. In tutorial you can see Problems running django-admin which suggests to use python -m django  instead of django-admin.

If you still get error then put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

Try opening up command prompt and run python -m django --version. If this doesn't work, then post the full error because running the command with python -m should ideally give you a different error such as No module named django if python cannot find the installed program. This error will require different troubleshooting.

@Meganekogekkilove - You totally missed my point.  I'm talking about the instructor ... and his "requirement" that you use an EOL platform to match his out-of-date course material / laptop / whatever.

@StephenC I understand what you mean, and what I wanted you to know is that he said that while he wanted us to Django 2.0.2, we could still run whatever the latest version is. He just wanted us to use the same version as him, because we could follow the course easier.

@furas I edited my question to include the commands and FULL errors that are given. I have even included the commands and errors from both the Windows Command Prompt Terminal and the Windows Administrator: PowerShell. The errors given are the full errors copied and pasted, with nothing changed.

@shru I have tried your command and have edited my question to show your command, as well as other commands I have tried, and the errors produced by them. I have even shown those commands and their errors from both the Windows Command Prompt Terminal and the Windows Administrator: PowerShell.

maybe you have very common problem: you may have two Pythons installed and command pip installs module for one Python but command python runs other Python. You may need to use python -m pip install ... instead pip install ... (and also check python -m pip list instead of pip list. If you look on path in errors you may even see that python shows C:\Users\ngjph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 but pip shows c:\users\ngjph\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311

you may have to find both Pythons and uninstall one of them. I don't use Windows but as I remember it has function to uninstall programs and maybe there are both Pythons and you may uninstall one of them. OR you may have to manually delete folder with one of Pythons. And later it may need to install Django again. You may also check if there is pip.exe in C:\Users\ngjph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 and eventually use full path to run it C:\Users\ngjph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\pip list. On Linux I could use which pip to find full path to other pip to remove it

You have two pythons installed. Just using pip installs packages for one python but the actual command python is on a different path. You might need to do a full uninstall for both python or as a last resort, try running python -m pip install django then python -m django this should install Django for the current python path.

@furas Thank you. I understand the thing about the two Pythons. It seems very annoying, but I understand. However, I used the python -m pip install Django command, and it worked perfectly. Django installed as if I had never done it before.

@furas Next I tried the command that substitutes for Django-admin, but nothing happened. I got no output. Maybe it's not the right command, but what I'm trying to do is start Django where I can start coding. This is what I got when I used the command. PS C:\Users\ngjph> python -m django startproject first_project PS C:\Users\ngjph>
I should also explain that the instructor of the course I am taking, said that he didn't want us downloading Django from the official website. He said he'd explain why later in the video, but this big problem has kept me from getting to that part of the video.

did you use python -m pip install django ?  It installs django for Python which you use to run python -m django. if you use pip install ... then it install django in wrong place - for wrong Python. Forget this instructor - install django like millions people on the world. But more important can be if you have two Pythons installed. If you have two pythons installed then better remove one of them because it will always makes some problems. OR remove all Pythons, delete all folders which have subfolders Python311 and start from the beginning. Install fresh Python3.11 (maybe not 3.13)

maybe instructor asks to install this version because newer versions may have many  changes and he would have to create all tutorial from scratch.

@furas I did use the command python -m pip install django, but before I did it, I did pip uninstall django, so nothing would conflict. I tried to look, but I cannot find how old the course is. All I know is that the course is old enough that Django 2.0.2 was a working version at that time. I can also tell, from seeing the instructor's desktop, that he is using an older version of MacOS. As for Python itself, I installed Python the same way everyone does, using the website. The only Python module I have installed from online is Anaconda. All other modules have been installed using pip.

@furas I have used the Python IDLE for coding, but I also have other editors. I have PyCharm, Visual Studio, and I use the websites for Google Collaboratory and Replit. When I start a new coding course, I try to use whatever editor the instructors wants me to use. I have searched the Files Explorer for Django, in the OS (C:) folder, and different files and folders, such as resources or tools. I also saw an application file called "django-admin", but when I double-click on it, a window opens up, which looks like the Command Prompt/PowerShell window, but before anything can load, it closes out

@furas From all the files that I see, when I searched for Django in my Files Explorer, I can see plugins, compiled Python files, Python Source Files, JSFiles. as well as others. Since I am new to Django, I am assuming that all those files and folders are supposed to be there. Hopefully this new information can help.

django-admin doesn't have GUI - it is not for clicking but for running in command line. You have to first open Command Prompt, and next write command manually with options. WIthout options it has nothing to do. But I still think that all problem is mess with two Pythons. You have to clear it all and start from the beginning.

BTW: django is powerfull tool with many functions but ... it is hard at start. It needs to generate project, set settings in file, create code in few files at start, etc. For small project (and at start) Flask is much simpler - you have to create only one file (and you can do it manually without using any generator) and you can put all code in one file. So at start it much easier. But later when you need more complex task then Flask need to search and add extensions - and Django usually already have it.

@furas Using a virtual environment seems to be working so far. I will see if I can use it for my course. So far, things are going well with it.

@furas After trying the virtual environment, I decided to see if Django would work outside of the virtual environment, and it did. Sadly, I have a new problem. When I try using the link Django gives me, to see if everything is working properly, all I see is a browser page telling me that the website can't be reached.

when you start django in console then it shows all connections and errors. Do you see any error? OR maybe you used wrong IP in code - servers usually may use 0.0.0.0 but client/browser has to use http://127.0.0.1, And client may need to use http:// instead of https://

if it works outside venv then maybe delete this venv and create new one using python which you use to run code /full/path/to/python3.11 -m venv ...

@furas Thank you. I have figured things out, and gotten Django to work so far. I can see the "The install worked successfully! Congratulations!" page, and hopefully, Django continues to work properly for me.

i would suggest you create an environment variable with venv
and the try to do your installations there, I know a youtube channel that can help with installing python and django correctly in a windows system
you can check him out here

Thank you for your answer. But could you post the exact video link from the person's YouTube channel?

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEsfXFp6DpzQjDBvhNy5YbaBx9j-ZsUe6
this is the link here for the python tutorial
